# jquery.animate is only working once

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image which rotates 360 degrees using .hover, however the animation will only occur once. Here's a little fiddle.

[Here's a little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNa7t/)

I am not sure how to fix this, I think its to do with animation itself being finished and needing to be restarted but.

```
$('#PSLogo').hover(function () {
    $('#PSLogo').animate({
        rotate: 360
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: 'slow'
    }, 'linear');
});
```

Is the code for the rotation

Comment: There is restricted access to view your images on your domain, even when provided in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use CSS3 transforms? Javascript seems a little heavy for a simple transform.

```
#PSLogo {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
#PSLogo:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

If you want it for all of them you can use

```
.logo {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.logo:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

And just add the `.logo` class to the elements you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNa7t/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm completing Ben's answer about your initial animation. It could be done much simpler with a recursive function call :

```
function startingAnimation($el) {
    $el.animate({
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    }, function() {
        $next = $el.next('img');
        if ($next.length) {
            startingAnimation($next);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    startingAnimation($('#PSLogo'));
});
```

Also if you want the animation only on `mouseenter` and not `mouseleave` you have to add the `transition` rule to the hover only.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XNa7t/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using plain css would be the easier approach here, but incase you have a valid reason for needing this, this should do it:

```
var interval = "";

$('#PSLogo').hover(function () {
    interval = setInterval("animate()",1000);
});

$('#PSLogo').on("mouseleave", function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});

function animate(){
    $('#PSLogo').animate({
        rotate: 360
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: 1000
    }, 'linear');
}
```